# how to type in input field that have the same class name with another input field in Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I have more then 1 input field that have class ".input-tag" but each of input field placed inside 1 div with different id. How do I type in each field? because when I do $browser->type('.input-tag', 'value') it'll only type in the first one it's found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer for my own question.
It's not using $browser->type for this case, it's using $browser->value.
By using it, we can target the selector for input field